# Как прикрепить вложение чат боту через vk api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, flask

Делал бота по этой [статье](https://habr.com/post/326898/)

На моменте поиска картинок по странице вылетает ошибка 
`vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 5. User authorization failed: no access_token passed`

Токены, как в статье написаны, я делал. Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я использовал метод, который требует авторизации под пользователем, а не под сообществом.